# Wrapping jar into a dll

Tags: java, excel, j-interop, vba

I want to make a COM server packaged in a DLL for use from VBA-Excel.
The functionality will be provided by Java classes packaged in a jar.
How do I do this?

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.teamdev.com/comfyj. Bear in mind that whatever you do is going to involve starting up the JVM etc - it's far from trivial.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the comment. My problem would be solved if Java 8/9 still had the ActiveX bridge, but it was discontinued.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358282/javabeans-activex-bridge-for-java-8

Answer (score 1):

For calling Java code from Excel you can use Jinx, the Excel Java Add-In.

See https://exceljava.com for details.

Using Jinx you can write a full Excel add-in including user defined worksheet functions and macros in Java, without any need for COM or VBA.